# Milestones, is it possible to have two active entitlements on one case?

Tags: entitlements, entitlement-process

I got this business rule request I am not sure Salesforce can manage, just want your input on it.

Is it possible have two Milestones/Entitlements active in one case at the same time, the reason for this would be to have one for the customer SLA and a second only to remind the support staff to periodically send a status update to the customer.

I guess I could create some sort of reminder using the process builder with some tinkering but my manager asked for the milestones at first hand.

Answer (score 0):

I did post a question to salesforce support, they proposed me to use a process builder item for this.

They also cautioned me to make sure to look in to the business hours when setting it up, it seem the process builder has a known issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not possible to have two Entitlements active on one case leveraging out-0f-the-box features (Because there is only one entitlement process lookup that can be set per case), is it quite feasible to have two Milestones active on a case at once. One of the reasons for enable individual Milestones as its own concept under the Entitlement process is support exactly this use case. From your explanation of the two sets of Milestones you want to track, it seems you'd like one for the "customer SLA" and one to reminder the support team to "follow-up" every x number of hours/days.

To achieve this, your would configure two different Milestones:
(1) "Customer SLA" (which maybe could called "Resolution" but I am not sure what type of SLA you are referring to in the context of this question)

- Recurrence Type = No Recurrence
- Entry Criteria = Case creation
  (2) "Follow-up"
- Recurrence Type = Independent
- Entry Criteria = Whenever Case is edited AND status = "Blocked" & Status Reason = "Customer Follow-up" (Or whatever data setup you're using to track this unique scenario)

Hope that helps, two years later. :)